# Project libraries don't show in Altium 14.1

Tags: schematics, altium, library

I am having strange issue, because when I open my schematic document and try to add component, when I click on Libraries (it doesn't show my project libraries).
[Libraries](http://prntscr.com/a7pyf8). 
I try to edit in Preferences my paths and default locations but still can not resolve it.
My project has two libraries (schematic and pcb), I can see pcb (footprints and 3D models) but can not see components (schematic). 
[PCB libraries (footprints)](http://prntscr.com/a7q09r)

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

Shouldn't Altium anyhow show libraries that are part of my project (in project tree) and are in same folder with project, not linked to the project but directly added?

EDIT:

I tried to set paths to the libraries, to be relative and absolute, neither one worked. Is it possible to be some kind of a bug in Altium? Because Altium 13 works fine with same preference setings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the **Libraries** button, and then click the **Installed** tab. You should have a list of the libraries that are installed. You may have to Install the libraries again, or you may have to click the **Activated** check box to get them to show up.

Answer (score 0):

1. First go to view
2. Then click default layout
3. Then click default
4. Then it's gonna show you many bars, then you use or cut it out.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question....